# Rewrite date/time format with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, time

I have be looking around for a solution for this but cant find anything. I am trying to reformat the date and time entered into a form, ideally with jQuery. I am not using the datepicker.
I am trying to rewrite dates so they come out in the format “dd/mm/yyyy” so if the user enters “050812”, “05082012”, “05-08-2012” etc the date gets rewtirred to “dd/mm/yyyy”. I am also trying to achieve this with time fields so the format will be “hh:mm”.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: did you look for date.js? it may help you.

Comment: How do you plan to determine whether the user intentionally *meant* the fifth of August, 2012 or the eighth of May, 2012? Unless you're using individual input elements for the day and the month, I'd suggest simply asking the user what they intended (assuming that both alternatives are valid dates, if they typed `12/13/2012` then obviously that *has* to be the thirteenth of December (or a typo)).

Comment: May I suggest that if you're going to rewrite the date format you use dd MMM yyyy as in 05 AUG 2012? Avoids ambiguity.

Comment: best is to show user calendar (datepicker from jquery-ui) and never allow him to enter date  manual

Comment: @eicto that would be ideal however im dealing with large date ranges and they are going to have to go through month by month. I am however going to liik into datepicker more as this will probably be the best way for now.

Comment: Displaying the month and year menus within datepicker seems to be the bast way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @eicto said, datepicker is the best option.

But if you really want another way:

To show the to the user what's the right way to enter data: http://jsfiddle.net/bmSPs/1/
To mask the input: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

OBS: If you want a more powerful way to control the hour you could also use http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html

Comment: Thank you i have had a play with datepicker and it is looking like the best option. Thanks to all

Comment: If you want the same style for both date picker and time picker you could use this: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/. See the "Show only the time picker without date picker" example, i think will help you.

Comment: That is fantastic however i need to be exact with times and the sliders are tricky to get an exact minuet. I will look into this more though, thank you